# Mapping a function of the form matrix[[row,column1;;column2]] over a list

Tags: matrix, function-construction

I want to create a list of lists of values by mapping `values[[row, col1;;col2]]` over a list like `{{r1,c1,c2},{r2,c2,c3},... }` to end up with a few hundred rows of about 30 values.  The r1,c1 ... values refer to a 9000 by 5000 matrix. I tried to use

```
MapThread[matrix[[#1,#2;;#2]]&, (* lists of triplets *)]
```

but that doesn't work. This is probably simple, but I'm not coming up with the answer.

Comment: does `matrix[[#, #2 ;; #3]] & @@@ triplets` work?

Comment: @kguler It doesn't seem to, but it seems like it should. I'm going to work with a little.

Comment: Yes! It does work.  I've never used @@@ before.  Apply on steroids. Simple and beautiful. Thanks.

Comment: George, `@@@` is probably my [favorite operator](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A121+%22%40%40%40%22) in all of *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
matrix[[#, #2 ;; #3]] & @@@ triplets
```

A `20` by `10` example:

```
matrix = RandomInteger[10, {20, 10}];
matrix // TableForm
```

[image]

```
triplets = Flatten/@Transpose[{RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {8}], Sort/@RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {8, 2}]}]
```

> {{14, 5, 10}, {11, 4, 10}, {2, 2, 10}, {10, 8, 10}, {12, 3, 9}, {3, 3, 5}, {6, 4, 7}, {5, 5, 10}}

```
matrix[[#, #2 ;; #3]] & @@@ triplets // TableForm
```

[image]

```
MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, matrix, {#, #2 ;; #3} & @@@ triplets] // TableForm
```

[image]

Note: Among many alternative ways, you can also use

```
Rest@Extract[matrix, Join @@ {{{}}, {#, #2;;#3} & @@@ triplets}]
```

Answer (score 3):

you still can use `MapThread`. consider the example given by kguler:

```
MapThread[matrix[[#, #2 ;; #3]] &, Transpose[triplets]]
```

Comment: I'm happy to see that you CAN use MapThread.

Answer (score 2):

Although I prefer kguler's method I don't want to be left out of the fun therefore:

```
Cases[triplets, {r_, c1_, c2_} :> matrix[[r, c1 ;; c2]]]
```

Comment: Cases[] seems, to me, to be a function with an especially high level of abstraction. I suppose that is because it works with the structure of things rather than the values of things.  I'm always pleased when I can do something this way. So, very nice.